# Image isn't drawn again after Touch

Tags: java, android

I have a **"Board.java"** class, which is an activity, and a **"MySurfaceView.java"**, which is a SurfaceView. I'm drawing some bitmap on the SurfaceView and I want to move it when the screen is touched (to the touched place). it draws the bitmap but after touching, nothing happened.
Thanks in advance!

**Log:**

```
Cancelling event due to no window focus: MotionEvent { action=ACTION_CANCEL, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=539.47266, y[0]=978.45703, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=90656, downTime=88761, deviceId=0, source=0x1002 }
```

**Board.java:**

```
    package com.myfirstapplication.owner.appversion1;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Created by Owner on 15/06/2016.
 */

public class Board extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnTouchListener {
    TextView tv;
    MySurfaceView mv;
    Bitmap bp;
    float x, y;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mv = new MySurfaceView(this);
        mv.setOnTouchListener(this);
        bp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.missile_cartoon);
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
        setContentView(mv);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mv.pause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mv.resume();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(50);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        x = event.getX();
        y = event.getY();

        return true;
    }

   }
```

**MySurfaceView.java:**

```
    package com.myfirstapplication.owner.appversion1;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

/**
 * Created by Owner on 16/06/2016.
 */
public class MySurfaceView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {
    float x, y;
    Bitmap bp;
    Thread t = null;
    SurfaceHolder holder;
    boolean isItOK = false;


    public MySurfaceView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        Bitmap bpOld = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.missile_cartoon);
        bp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bpOld, 250, 250, true);
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
        holder = getHolder();
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(isItOK){
            if(!holder.getSurface().isValid())
                continue;
            Canvas c = holder.lockCanvas();
            c.drawARGB(255,150,150,10);
            c.drawBitmap(bp,x-(bp.getWidth()/2),y-(bp.getHeight()/2),null);
            holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
        }
    }

    public void pause() {
        isItOK = false;
        while(true){
            try{
                t.join();
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
        }
        t = null;
    }

    public void resume() {
        isItOK = true;
        t = new Thread(this);
        t.start();
    }



}
```

Comment: @antonio yes though I got no answer and I don't know what to do.

Comment: Take a look at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128226/can-i-ask-same-question-again-if-nobody-has-answered and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160902/how-should-we-treat-a-user-that-asks-the-same-question-again-and-again